# Calling Objective C block in swift weak self always nill

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, closures, objective-c-blocks

I have a block property in Objective C .h file
I'm creating variable of Objective C controller in swift file with this code

```
let viewController = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
        
viewController.onCellPressed = { [weak self] cellModel in
    guard let cellModel = cellModel else { return }
    self?.openDetails(cellModel)
}
```

Here is the declaration of block var

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onCellPressed)(CellModel* model);
```

And I'm running this block with this code

```
self.onCellPressed([_photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
```

The issue is that `[weak self]` inside

```
    { [weak self] cellModel in
        guard let cellModel = cellModel else { return }
        self?.openDetails(cellModel)
    }
```

is always `nil`

How to use weak self inside the block in swift file?

Comment: Is the block even called? Seeing just the code as such, I'm wondering if `viewController` which seems to be a local var isn't released too soon.

Comment: Yes, it calls. This controller is created in coordinator, so it has to be in memory. Also in case I'm using strong self inside the block it works as I expect

Comment: "This controller is created in coordinator, so it has to be in memory" It depends, is the coordinator kept in memory too? Is it not a local var too? Do you have a reproducible example app?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share a runnable code to test.